# How do I determine the size of the editing control in a UITableViewCell delete style?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView where the height of each row is calculated in

```
heightForRowAtIndexPath
```

The rows also use

```
UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete
```

to delete rows. The problem is that the calculated height of some rows is smaller than the editing control (red circle on left) displayed in the edit mode which cuts off the top of the editing control.

How can I determine the height of the editing control so I can ensure the row height is no smaller than the editing control height?

Comment: Don't make UITableViewCells smaller than 44 points tall?

Comment: On the Mac you can use Shift+Command+4 to capture an arbirary rectangle on the screen.  This will show you the width and height of whatever you select, so run your app in the simulator and measure it.  But @markAdams is right, keep the min at or above 44.

Comment: I would rather determine the necessary height programmatically than hard code a value that might change.