# How do I determine the origin (x,y) of the Delete button for a UITableViewCell during editing mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that uses the standard delete editing style. I want to resize the text in the cell when the Delete button is displayed so it is visible.

How do I determine the origin of the standard Delete button so I can calculate the proper frame size for the resized text?

EDIT:
This is a subclassed UITableViewCell that contains a UILabel. The amount of text in the label varies from row to row so the height of the cell is calculated for each row and the UILabel frame adjusted accordingly when the cell is created.

I have tried adjusting the autoresizingMask of the UILabel in the cell as described in the comments and it has no effect on the layout of the text in the label when the edit (Delete) mode is active.

EDIT #2:
As requested here are some screen captures.

a) Here's the table cells w/ the UILabel control. The height of each cell is dynamically calculated based upon the amount of text.

[image: Before edit]

b) When the Edit mode starts the editing control (red circle) is displayed which pushes the text off the right side of the screen.

[image: Edit control displayed, text off screen]

c) Then when an editing control is selected and the Delete button is displayed it overlaps the text.

[image: Delete button overlaying text]

The objective is to have the text area (UILabel frame) reduce it's width and increase the height to accommodate all the text when editing starts "b)". When the Delete button is displayed "c)" the text height would stay the same and the text that does not fit can be truncated and an elipsis "..." displayed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of the editing control in a UITableViewCell delete style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391092/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-the-editing-control-in-a-uitableviewcell-delete-s)

Comment: The editing control (red circle on the left) is different than the Delete button (right). That is a separate question I posted.

Comment: Are you using the `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties of `UITableViewCell`, or are you displaying the text in your own private subview of the cell?

Comment: It is a subclass of UITableViewCell that has a UILabel.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to - if you've added your subviews to the content view of the cell and set their resizing mask appropriately, this will happen automatically for you.

By resizing mask, I mean the options visible in the size inspector in interface builder. For example, if you want the cell to stay a fixed distance from the left and right margins, but grow or shrink in width, then you change the margin and width bars so that the preview shows the label growing and shrinking as opposed to staying the same size but moving around. I can't remember the specific appearance and I'm not at my mac at the moment, sorry, but it should be pretty obvious.

Comment: The cell is created from a nib file and as shown in the edit of the question above the edit control is being cut off. Please elaborate on what you mean by "set their resizing mask...". Thanks

Comment: Presumably he means [`autoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6).

Comment: Set edited question. Changing the autoresizingMask has no effect of the text in the label in edit mode.

Comment: So, to clarify, you are manually setting the frame for quite a large label in heightForRow, and you want the label to resize (and presumably the height of the cell to increase?) so you can still accommodate the full text? Can you include some screenshots in your question?

Comment: Additional info added in Edit#2

Comment: It is more usual for long text to be truncated in editing mode... It is considerably harder to recalculate and update the cell height when going into editing mode than just to adjust the label width. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: For an example of what I mean, try to delete a email in the iPhone mail app.